# How can I convert monthly data to yearly data in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

My data looks like that:

| data_dte | Year | Month | usg_apt | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/1990 | 1990 | 1 | JFK | 80 |
| 01/1990 | 1990 | 1 | MIA | 100 |
| 01/1990 | 1990 | 1 | ORD | 58 |

I want to have a yearly total for each "usg_apt" instead of monthly.
"usg_apt" stands for "US Gateway Airport Code".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dataframe in question is called df, maybe you could try df.groupby(["usg_apt", "Year"])['Total'].agg('sum').

Comment: I used this code df_intl2019.groupby(["Year", "usg_apt"])["Total"].sum(). But the code you shared gives more elegant resutls. Thank you so much.  If I might ask,  from this output how can I extract the max value for usg_apt?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is something like this df.groupby(["usg_apt", "Year"])['Total'].agg('sum').reset_index().max()["usg_apt]